# MySQL query - SELECT only the latest result of a specific row?

Tags: mysql, date, select, where-clause

I've got this query that is about to create a bill automatically via cronjob if the date of an expired coupon is exactly 1 month ago OR the last bill-date (`b.date`) is exactly one month ago. The conditions can only happen once, because the specific date will never be 1 month ago in the future.

```
SELECT *

FROM `coupons` AS c 
LEFT JOIN `partners` AS p ON p.`id` = c.`pid`
LEFT JOIN `bills` AS b ON b.`pid` = c.`pid`   

WHERE 
(
CURRENT_DATE() = DATE_ADD(c.`expires`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // add something here?
OR
CURRENT_DATE() = DATE_ADD(b.`date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
)
```

My problem is that in the first WHERE-condition I got more than 1 result. So I'm looking for a solution to only select the latest and only one row of `b.date` also.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you determine what the "latest" one is?  Are there any fields in the table that could give you that information?

Comment: Yes. The b.`date` (date of the bill) should be the latest. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just add 'LIMIT 1' at the end: see the [MySQL documentation for select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

But note that you'll have to add an ORDER BY to ensure that you get the 'latest' row, depending on what you mean by that - `bills.date` or `coupons.expires`?

Comment: But wouldn't this limit to get other possible results I need? I want to use this query for a while-loop to get all specific data for a specific partner (`partners`).

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, I misunderstood your question - it's not that you want to limit the rows, but rather prevent duplicates. Surely you're still getting duplicate coupon rows, but just occurring further down in the list? How about rather using a sub-query? I'll mock up an example...

Comment: That would be nice of you. My problem is now that I'll get only one result with `ORDER BY MAX(b.date) DESC` at the end of this query, but the b.date can't be right, because it isn't one month ago. I have two test-rows in `bills` with the b.date 2011-12-12 and 2010-12-12 and he selects the 2010 one... kinda strange?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Max function on the bills.date row if you want to use the latest result (see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp).

Comment: That worked! I've put `ORDER BY MAX(b.date) DESC` at the end. Thank you.

Comment: Well, my problem now is that I'll get only one result with `ORDER BY MAX(b.date) DESC` at the end of this query, but the b.date can't be right, because it isn't one month ago. I have two test-rows in `bills` with the b.date 2011-12-12 and 2010-12-12 and he selects the 2010 one... kinda strange?

Comment: Try this on the first WHERE-condition (CURRENT_DATE() = DATE_ADD(c.`expires`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (b.`date` = select MAX(bill.`date`) from `bills` AS bill WHERE c.`pid` = bill.`pid`))

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `bills` relate to the `partners` and not to the `coupons`. Your SQL, for example, is like this:

```
  drop table if exists coupons;
  create table coupons (id int not null, pid int not null, expires date, primary key(id));
  drop table if exists bills;
  create table bills (id int not null, pid int not null, `date` date, primary key(id));
  drop table if exists partners;
  create table partners ( id int, name varchar(20), primary key(id));
```

We populate with some data:

```
  insert into partners values (1,'One');
  insert into coupons values (1,1,'2011-12-12'), (2,1,'2011-11-11');
  insert into bills values (1,1,'2011-12-12'), (2,1,'2011-11-11');
```

At this point

```
  select * from coupons c
  left join partners p on c.pid = p.id
  left join bills b on b.pid = c.pid
```

returns 4 rows, which makes sense: (partner1, coupon1, bill1), (p1, c1, b2), (p1, c2, b1), (p1, c2, b2). If we add:

```
  where
  (
  current_date() = date_add(c.expires, interval 1 month)
  or
  current_date() = date_add(b.`date`, interval 1 month)
  )
```

We get 3 rows: (p1, c1, b1), (p1, c1, b2), (p1, c2, b1). Why? Because neither of coupon2 or bill2 succeeds on the test, whereas at least one of each of the other combinations does.

I suspect what you're really looking for is closer to:

```
  select *
  from coupons c
  where
  c.id in
  (select distinct c2.id from coupons c2 
    left join partners p2 on c2.pid=p2.id
    left join bills b2 on b2.pid=c2.pid
    where
     current_date()=date_add(c2.expires, interval 1 month)
     or
     current_date()=date_add(b2.`date`, interval 1 month)
  )
```

Here I'm using a subquery to get the list of distinct coupon ids for coupons matching your requirement, then just retrieving those coupons.

But, playing with it, I'm not sure your requirement exactly makes sense: you're retrieving coupons which either have an expiry date exactly one month ago, or which are associated with a partner who was billed exactly one month ago? In this approach, you only get the coupon list, and would then need to retrieve the latest bill or the partner details, assuming there is always an associated partner? Is there?

Hope that helps, Craig

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your time to help me with this! Thank you. I dont have much experience with subqueries and should have told you what data I need. I  wrote * to make it short here, but I really need to select `p.email`, `c.id` and `p.id`. So I dont need any data from `bills`. I want to send an email to the partner that a new bill has been created and insert a new bill in `bills` with the c.id (coupon-id) and p.id (partner-id). Could you give me any further advice how to solve this? Thanks again!

Comment: Is there one-and-only-one partner per coupon? (It's a pleasure!)

Comment: Yes, there can't be another for one coupon. But one partner can have multiple coupons. This system is like the Groupon system.

Comment: If there's always one-and-only-one partner, you can use `select * from coupons c inner join partners p on c.pid=p.id where c.id in (select distinct c2.id from coupons c2 left join partners p2 on c2.pid=p2.id left join bills b2 on b2.pid=c2.pid where current_date()=date_add(c2.expires, interval 1 month) or current_date()=date_add(b2.``date``, interval 1 month))` (aargh - single back ticks, but can't use them here because of syntax highlighting). Use **left join** if there's the chance that there isn't a partner. All the best, C

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and wanted to add p.`email` and p.`id` in the subquery to select these rows, but it doesnt seem to work. Maybe because of the DISTINCT? I added it like that: "select distinct c2.id,p2.email,p.id from coupons c2 ....". PS: You could also edit your main post here if you want to highlight your syntax and dont have to answer in the comment section here.

Comment: A subquery like that can only return a list of single values - just the relevant ID's for the coupons you want. Add the other values you want into the main select. Thanks for the PS: I always worry whether changing above won't make all the comments seem nonsensical!

Comment: I see. But like I mentioned, I just have to check for c.`expires` once. It's because this is the day a coupon ended. And that date won't come up again. So I don't really need other select-values of `coupons` but `coupon.id`. If one bill is created, I only want to check for b.`date` (date of latest bill) in the future to create a new bill. Do you know what I mean? Because I can't select values from other tables in the main select with this subquery. About "comments seem nonsensical": I guess if someone looks at the last-updated time it will make sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works on MySQL but what about `LIMIT 1`

Comment: That would be nice, if I only could limit one specific row like `b.date`. But if I'm adding LIMIT at the end of the query I'll limit all given results to only 1. And I need the other results.

Comment: How about getting your current date before the where clause, say into a temporary table - you could then limit the results?

Comment: I added `ORDER BY MAX(b.date) DESC` to solve this. But thank you!